# SwiftUI and ScrollView: Views Disappear After Device Rotation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The view is composed with SwiftUI, and the List contains several rows where each row holds a ScrollView with the items. It is similar to Apple's SwiftUI Landmark tutorial (https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/composing-complex-interfaces). When I rotate the device (tested on real iPhone XS), the content of the ScrollView disappears. The issue is not present when I replace the ScrollView with another element, such as Text. Thus, the issue must somehow be related to the use of ScrollView. Please see below the screenshots and the SwiftUI code.

**Behavior**

[image]

**Code**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: InsigniaContainer.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \InsigniaContainer.sort, ascending: true),
        ],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "parentContainer == NULL")
    ) var insigniaContainers: FetchedResults<InsigniaContainer>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.insigniaContainers, id: \.objectID) { (insigniaContainer: InsigniaContainer) in
                    ServiceBranchRow(serviceBranch: insigniaContainer)
                }
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Armed Forces")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}



struct ServiceBranchRow: View {
    var serviceBranch: InsigniaContainer

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Text(self.serviceBranch.wrappedName)
                .font(.headline)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .padding(.leading, 15)
                .padding(.top, 10)
            Spacer()
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 15) {
                    ForEach(self.serviceBranch.sortedChildContainers, id: \.objectID) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: InsigniaList(insigniaContainer: item)) {
                            ServiceBranchItem(item: item)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(10)
                .padding(.leading, 5)
                .padding(.trailing, 5)
                .padding(.bottom, 5)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have iPhone XS, is it reproducible on simulator?

Comment: @Asperi Yes, it is also reproducible on Simulator.

Comment: Then, I suppose, the origin is in your custom subviews, because I replaced them in provided snapshot with `Rectangle()` of *160x100* dimension and tested with iPhone X simulator (Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2), and all works.

Comment: Replaced the entire content of ScrollView, i.e. HStack, with Rectangle().frame(width: 230.0, height: 150.0), but nothing changes.

Comment: Just did the same - works fine. Which Xcode version do you use?

Comment: Xcode 11.3.1. Just added a GIF to the question, might help you to understand the issue better.

Comment: You forgot the space force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh... that issue... known effect - it is due to List caching... it thinks that all scroll views are same.

The fix is simple - just add unique id *exactly* for scrollview, like below

```swift
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    HStack(spacing: 15) {
        ForEach(self.serviceBranch.sortedChildContainers, id: \.objectID) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: InsigniaList(insigniaContainer: item)) {
                ServiceBranchItem(item: item)
            }
        }
    }
    .padding(10)
    .padding(.leading, 5)
    .padding(.trailing, 5)
    .padding(.bottom, 5)
}
.id(UUID().uuidString) // !! here
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Asperi, saved my day.

Comment: @Asperi using `.id(UUID().uuidString)` increases the CPU usage percentage from 33% to 70%.